# persist bot chat data in bot framework wrt to Form Flow

Tags: save, botframework

I want to know whether is there any feature in bot framework to get the user and bot chat completely. I have gone through the official documentation, but the way I understood it is that, only to that context we can save the chat data. If at all we have to store the whole data, we have to take care of it. 
I tried using this,

```
StateClient sc = activity.GetStateClient();
BotData userData1 = 
sc.BotState.GetConversationData(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id);

userData1.Data = userData1.Data + activity.Text;
sc.BotState.SetConversationData(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, userData1);
```

This does persist the user data, but I am stuck with how to persist it in the form flow.
I am not sure how to persist data of bot and user wrt to **Form Flow** using SetConversationData. I even need the bot to persist the prompt message of the form flow. So that I ll have the complete conversation b/w user and the bot.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial may help:
[Introduction To FormFlow With The Microsoft Bot Framework](http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/8/Introduction-To-FormFlow-With-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework)

The data from the user is automatically persisted during the FormFlow. 
When the FormFlow is completed you can persist it like this:

```
public static IForm<ProfileForm> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<ProfileForm>()
            .Message("Welcome to the profile bot!")
            .OnCompletion(async (context, profileForm) =>
            {
                // Set BotUserData
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<bool>(
                    "ProfileComplete", true);
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>(
                    "FirstName", profileForm.FirstName);
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>(
                    "LastName", profileForm.LastName);
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>(
                    "Gender", profileForm.Gender.ToString());
                // Tell the user that the form is complete
                await context.PostAsync("Your profile is complete.");
            })
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try using it. But with this method, I get the value of the fields which I have used in form building. But I needed the whole conversation data. Do you know any ways to capture the whole conversation through **conversation ID**

Comment: I use: "Implementing A SQL Server Database With The Microsoft Bot Framework" http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/13/Implementing-A-SQL-Server-Database-With-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework

Comment: Thanks.. :) will look into it! :)